# Windows 7 not creating folder "new folder" on desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Windows 7 is displaying that ----

> Windows 7 is unable to create folder
>   "new folder"  the system can not find
>   the file specified

while it is creating new folder in other locations.
the right click menu contains new folder option .

Comment: Possible but unlikely it is a registry bug. http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/69837-new-folder.html I'm afraid Moab's answer is more likely the solution . . .

Answer (score 3):

The User profile you are logging into is probably corrupt, Make a new use account, then log out of your old one and then into your new one, can you make a folder on the new desktop?

If you can, migrate your old user profile over to your new one, scroll down to "Copying your user Profile [in this link](http://www.lockergnome.com/nexus/it/2004/12/15/get-it-done-recover-a-damaged-windows-xp-user-profile/)

Use the new user account for a few weeks, once you are satisfied with the new account, you can delete the old user account if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Your user profile might be corrupt, try to create a new account and then login to new one. If that work well backup all your files and move to new profile account.